# ContentObserver doesn't work for Browser Bookmarks on Nexus 7?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I register a ContentObserver to monitor Bookmarks changes of Chrome on Nexus 7, but there is not any callback get from onChange().

With the same code, I can get ContentObserver callback of Android default browser on other devices.

Does Chrome not support ContentObserver callback on Nexus 7?

Code as below:

```
    getApplication().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, true, observer);
```

...

```
static class HistoryOberser extends ContentObserver {

    public HistoryOberser() {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Log.d(TAG, "onChange: " + selfChange);
    }

}
```

Comment: So I realize this was a while ago but did you ever figure this out?  I can query the content provider but onchange never gets called.

Comment: Please refer my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use URI "content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks" for Android Crhome browser bookmarks can make the observer works.